# how to terminate or kill child thread in python GUI application on frame close

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, wxpython, multiprocessing, wxwidgets

I have written a python GUI application using wx.Python
Here below the code what it does on clicking start button in main frame it will launch a frame(MyForm) in separate thread where it print some text.What i need, on closing MyForm frame current child thread execution should terminate or kill and control should go back to main thread. All the code i have written in one module

```
import wx, wx.html
from threading import Thread
import wx
import control
import sys

class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Sample frame', size=(750, 350))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        '''
        button <start> to start the script
        '''
        self.button_start = wx.Button(self.panel,-1,"Start",pos=(100,220),size=(100,40))
        self.button_close = wx.Button(self.panel,-1,"Close",pos=(300,220),size=(100,40))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.click_start,self.button_start)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose,self.button_close)

    def click_start (self,event):
        self.MyTask()

    def MyTask(self):
        step_a = 1
        step_b = 50

        self.frame2 = MyForm().Show()
        TestingThread(step_a, step_b)

    def OnCloseWindow(self,event):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 
            "Do you really want to close this application?",
            "Confirm Exit", wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            self.Destroy()
        
class App(wx.App):

    def __init__(self, redirect=True, filename=None):

        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)

    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = Frame(parent=None, id=-1)  #Create Frame
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

    def OnExit(self):
        self.Exit()

class TestingThread(Thread):
"""Test Worker Thread Class."""

    def __init__(self,a, b):    
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.start() 

    def run(self):

        self.res=control.main(self.a, self.b)

class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self,aWxTextCtrl):
        self.out=aWxTextCtrl

    def write(self,string):
        self.out.WriteText(string)

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "wxPython Log Redirect Box",size= (500,300))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        log = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(500,300),
                          style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL|wx.TE_NOHIDESEL)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(log, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        # redirect text here
        redir=RedirectText(log)
        sys.stdout=redir

    def OnClose(self, event):

        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 
            "Do you really want to close this application?",
            "Confirm Exit", wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            self.Destroy()
            self.MakeModal(False)  

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = App(redirect=False)
    app.MainLoo
```

Comment: What OS do you use? If its windows, there is no way in Python to actually kill a thread, only processes can be "killed". If its Linux, this is different - here threads can be killed.

Comment: I am using windows. Can you please tell how to change my code to handle process?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using windows, Python is not able to actually "Kill" a thread while it is not terminated. There are a lot of possibilities how to solve this.
E.g.:

- Communicate with the Thread and tell it to stop
- Run the "worker" as external process (e.g. with popen)
- Use multiprocessing.Process

Here is an example for the last. Please note, that you will need to work with multiprocessing.Queue or IPC features (e.g. Pyro4) to communicate with the process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

import time
import wx


procs = []

def subproc():
    while True:
        print("Hello World")
        time.sleep(1)

def OnStart(event):
    myProc = Process(target=subproc)
    myProc.start()
    print("Started new process with PID {}".format(myProc.pid))
    procs.append(myProc)

def OnStop(event):
    for proc in procs:
        proc.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()

    frame = wx.Frame(None, -1)
    frame.Show()

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    btn1 = wx.Button(frame, -1, "Start")
    btn2 = wx.Button(frame, -1, "Stop")
    sizer.Add(btn1, 0)
    sizer.Add(btn2, 1)
    frame.SetSizer(sizer)
    frame.Fit()
    frame.Layout()
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, OnStart, id = btn1.GetId())
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, OnStop, id = btn2.GetId())
    app.MainLoop()
```